# Cleaning text strings in vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, string

I am trying to clean up a string from a text field that will be part of sql query.

I have created a function:

```vb
Private Function cleanStringToProperCase(dirtyString As String) As String
    Dim cleanedString As String = dirtyString
    'removes all but non alphanumeric characters except @, - and .'
    cleanedString = Regex.Replace(cleanedString, "[^\w\.@-]", "")
    'trims unecessary spaces off left and right'
    cleanedString = Trim(cleanedString)
    'replaces double spaces with single spaces'
    cleanedString = Regex.Replace(cleanedString, "  ", " ")
    'converts text to upper case for first letter in each word'
    cleanedString = StrConv(cleanedString, VbStrConv.ProperCase)

    'return the nicely cleaned string'
    Return cleanedString
End Function
```

But when I try to clean any text with two words, it strips ALL white space out.  "daz's bike" becomes "Dazsbike".  I am assuming I need to modify the following line:

```vb
   cleanedString = Regex.Replace(cleanedString, "[^\w\.@-]", "")
```

so that it also lets single white space characters remain.  Advice on how to do so is greatly received as I cannot find it on any online tutorials or on the MSDN site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: **Don't do this**.  You should use parameters.

Comment: SLaks can you expand on that answer a bit more with some example code?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean now.  I can't do that as I am adding a module to an existing vb application, and I am restricted in what I can do with the database.  As such, although of course you are right and a procedure would be better, I am having to do this in a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"[^\w\.,@\-\' ]"` instead of your pattern string.

Also, I would use

```
Regex.Replace(cleanedString, " +", " ")
```

instead of

```
Regex.Replace(cleanedString, "  ", " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you are not a big fan of regex...

```vb
Private Function cleanStringToProperCase(dirtyString As String) As String
    'specify valid characters
    Dim validChars As String = " @-.0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    'removes all but validChars'
    Dim cleanedString As String = dirtyString.Where(Function(c) validChars.Contains(c)).ToArray
    Dim myTI As Globalization.TextInfo = New Globalization.CultureInfo(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).TextInfo

    'return the nicely cleaned string'
    Return myTI.ToTitleCase(cleanedString.Trim)
End Function
```